# Convert Everything to A Specific Date Timezone before calling an API

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-core-2.2

We are seeking to convert everything to DateTimeZone Pacific Standard time.

1. Database team is not utilizing sql `datetimeoffset`
2. Web team could have set dates to Pacific Standard Timezone with Moment.Js Angular application settings, however is using Dates instead.

Many of this is too late to change, across database, 1000s of tables, and application code.

I am asked to resolve this, so any dates stored in database is converted to PST before each API .

I created static function called, `DateTimeExtensions.ToPacificTimeZone(newDateTime)`.

1) We created method ObjectDateTimeConverter, which traverses through All class DTO members, nested classes,
It finds Any Datetime class member, and runs the PacificTimeZone static function.

2) The method is called automatically before each API request, converting all the data automatically, with an ActionFilter Method before POST request.

a) I am curious if Microsoft has a Nuget package or setting to automatically convert everything to a 
certain time zone, before an API. b) Is there perhaps a data serialization technique or optimal way? This way, I do not have to write custom code .

```
public static class ObjectDateTimeConverter
{
    public static void ConvertToDefaultTimeZone(object inputObject)
    {
        var type = inputObject.GetType();

        foreach (PropertyInfo property in type.GetProperties())
        {
            if (property.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime) ||    
                property.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime?))
            {
                var newDateTime = (DateTime)(property.GetValue(inputObject));
                newDateTime = DateTimeExtensions.ToPacificTimeZone(newDateTime); // It property is Datetime, call conversion function 
                property.SetValue(inputObject, newDateTime);
            }

            if (property.PropertyType.IsClass && !(property.PropertyType == typeof(string))
            {
                ConvertToDefaultTimeZone(property.GetValue(inputObject));
            }
        }
    }
```

**WebAPI -API Interceptor: Filter Attribute**

Automatically calls DateConverter before each API on Request DTO Objects

```
public class DateTimeConverterAsyncFilterAttribute : IAsyncActionFilter
{
    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext actionExecutingContext, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        foreach (var actionExecutingContextItem in actionExecutingContext.ActionArguments) // Intercept all requests, and call datetime converter
        {
            if (actionExecutingContextItem.Value != null)
            {
                ObjectDateTimeConverter.ConvertToDefaultTimeZone(actionExecutingContextItem.Value);
            }
        }
        await next();
    }
}
```

**To Call Automatic Converter: place before a Controller or its Method**

```
[ServiceFilter(typeof(DateTimeConverterAsyncFilterAttribute))] 
[ApiController]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
```

Also, I heard reflection in this case is slow. Not sure if that's true, we are utilizing Net Core 2.2

Comment: Out of curiosity, what datatype _is_ the database using to store these dates? And, are these timestamps (so time is important), or just dates (only day/month/year is important)?

Comment: using sqlserver datetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JsonConverter for your problem . JsonDateTimeConverter convert every datetime in your api requests and responses to specific date timezone .

Try this :

```
public class JsonDateTimeConverter : DateTimeConverterBase
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(((DateTime)value).ConvertToDefaultTimeZone());
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        try
        {
            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(reader.Value.ToString())
                ? (object)null
                : reader.Value.ToString().ConvertToDefaultTimeZone();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return reader.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

And in startup :

```
        services.AddMvc()
            .AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new                     
                      JsonDateTimeConverter());
            })
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```